# Remmina and Vinagre alternatives for VNC with ssh-tunnel support

Tags: remmina, vinagre

I'm using Remmina for connect to other computers using VNC. But it's often buggy when I choose ssh-tunnel. Vinagre works better, but it's not able to manage bookmarks. Are there ways to solve problems with remmina and vinagre? Or are there better alternatives of this software?

Answer (score 0):

Remmina works well for me though I need to establish the ssh tunnel in a terminal before hand.

For a one step VNC through SSH solution I use [ssvnc](http://ssvnc.sourceforge.net/). After some initial setup for each connnection I can establish a link quickly. I don't like the VNC client as much as Vinagre or Remmina but it works well.